# Why my question was closed?

Tags: support, closed-questions, close-reasons

I'm referring to [this one](https://superuser.com/q/811298/170331).

The reason was *"Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise."*

I don't understand; I've tried to explain in detail my problem, what I wanted to achieve and what I've already tried, basically by explaining my situation I've tried to be more specific as possible and to provide all informations that I thought could help those that were to answer. Furthermore, I was interested in a working practical solution, not in a discussion or a comparison of various methods. Yet it was closed without giving me many explanations: should I reword it to make it less generic and more focused* ? The whole topic is too broad? I need some clues because I don't get the point.

I've only received a comment stating that *"This subject is well documented there is no "best" method"*, but even here I fail to interpret its meaning: does that mean that what I want to achieve can't be done? That it can be done in several equivalent ways? That I can satisfy some of my requirements but not all of them together? From what can understand, it seems that I have asked a common question that already has some answers somewhere, but I wasn't given any information about them or pointed to those resources. Are those informations available on this site or somewhere else?

In the end, can I get some specific explanations? If I need to improve my question, these rather vague clues are not sufficient to me to find out how to do it.

Please note that I'm not arguing or complaining, I just want to understand.

*even if I don't see how to do that, I have already explained my problem in detail.

Comment: "Best" means there's one single superlatively great way that obsoletes everything else. "How do I" is probably a better choice of words.

Comment: That was not what I meant, it seemed to me that my question was open to any suggestion; anyway I have rephrased it.

Comment: @sekhemty Any suggestion would make it a very broad question, the problem is, the world of backing up a movie is complicated.  It's illegal to write software that works around the drm that protects movies, but in the US, it's legal to make personal backups.  So you are not going to have a lot of options

Comment: My comment was indicating that there are hundreds of articles on how to copy a movie DVD and there is no best method to do so.

Comment: Yes, like I said I wasn't complaining. I'm not looking for a "best" method, I'm looking to find how to do it in a way that work for me, as I've described on my question; anyway, if you would you be so kind to give me some directions about those articles I could upvote your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see a problem with this post, so I've reopened it.

It's specific enough, describes the problem in great detail, and also includes what you've already tried to solve it (and why that didn't work).

(A comment like "This subject is well documented there is no 'best' method"  isn't really helpful either. It should at least point to a solution or explain how the question can be improved.)

Comment: Thank you for your help.